# Join with case statement in tsql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    RootId int,
    Direction bit,
   ....
);
```

Now, I must write select from this table and join some tables to it. Joined tables depends on Direction parameter. How to join MyTable3 like here:

```
 select 
  Root,
  Direction,
  Type
 from MyTable
 join MyTable1 on 
   MyTable1.Id = RootId
 join MyTable2 on 
   MyTable2.Id = RootId

 join MyTable3 on 
   ...
   case select when Direction = 1
     MyTable3.TypeId = MyTable1.TypeId
   else
     MyTable3.TypeId = MyTable2.TypeId
```

Comment: Edit your question and include fully qualified column names so it is clear where the columns are coming from.

Comment: `on (Direction = 1 and myTable3.TypeId = myTable1.TypeId) or (Direction != 1 and  myTable3.TypeId = myTable2.TypeId)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The predicate of a `CASE` expression (i.e what the `CASE` expression generates) cannot be an equality condition, but rather it has to be a value.  You may write the final join condition as follows:

```
INNER JOIN MyTable3 t3
    ON (Direction = 1 AND t3.TypeId = t1.TypeId) OR
       (Direction <> 1 AND t3.TypeId = t2.TypeId)
```

Here is the full query:

```
SELECT 
    Root,
    Direction,
    Type
FROM MyTable t
INNER JOIN MyTable1 t1
    ON t1.Id = t.RootId
INNER JOIN MyTable2 t2
    ON t2.Id = t.RootId
INNER JOIN MyTable3 t3
    ON (Direction = 1 AND t3.TypeId = t1.TypeId) OR
       (Direction <> 1 AND t3.TypeId = t2.TypeId);
```

Answer (score 1):

For performance reasons, you may want to be using two `left join`s, like this:

```
select Root,Direction,
      coalesce(m3_1.Type, m3_2.Type) as type
from MyTable join
     MyTable1 
     on MyTable1.Id = MyTable.RootId join
     MyTable2
     on MyTable2.Id = MyTable.RootId left join
     MyTable3 m3_1
     on m3_1.Direction = 1 and
        m3_1.TypeId = MyTable1.TypeId left join
     MyTable3 m3_0
     on m3_2.Direction = 1 and
        me_2.TypeId = MyTable2.TypeId;
```

The use of `or` or `case` (or really anything other than `and` in an `on` clause) can have a big impact on performance.